# Scala Variable Pattern: variable is not assigned

Tags: scala, variables, pattern-matching

In `Scala for the impatient (2nd Edition)` the author says:

> If the case keyword is followed by a variable name, then the match
>   expression is assigned to that variable.

Also, similar statement is given in [Programming Scala, 2nd Edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-scala-2nd/9781491950135/ch04.html).

I'm using Scala 2.13. So I have the following codes:

```
object helloworld extends App {
  val a: Any = 1
  val x = a match{
    case 2 => 22
    case m: String => "aa"
    case n: Int => 11
  }

  println(s"$x  $m $n")
}
```

The IDE reports error: the value m and n are not found. **Now even if I define the m and n variable beforehand, they are not assigned as the book said**:

```
object helloworld extends App {
  var m: Any = ()
  var n: Any = ()
  val a: Any = 1
  val x = a match {
    case 2 => 22
    case m: String =>
      println(s"m = $m")
      "aa"
    case n: Int =>
      println(s"n = $n")
      11
  }

  //  println(s"$x  $m $n") 
  println(s"x = $x")
  println(s"m = $m n = $n")
}
```

**Is there something different in Scala 2.13, or is there something I've done wrong?**
Thanks.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a Scope problem. `m` and `n` are not visible outside the Pattern Matching case.

This works:

```
object helloworld extends App {
  val a: Any = 1
  val x = a match{
    case 2 => 22
    case m: String =>
      println(s"m = $m")
      "aa"
    case n: Int =>
      println(s"n = $n")
      11
  }

  println(s"x = $x")
}
```

Prints:

```
n = 1
x = 11
```

**Solution to the Updated Question:**:

```
object helloworld extends App {
  var m: Any = ()
  var n: Any = ()
  val a: Any = 1
  val x = a match {
    case 2 => 22
    case m1: String =>
      m = m1
      "aa"
    case n1: Int =>
      n = n1
      11
  }

  println(s"x = $x")
  println(s"m = $m n = $n")
}
```

Prints:

```
x = 11
m = () n = 1
```

**But this is not good *Scala* style!**

Answer (score 4):

This wording is sloppy:

> If the case keyword is followed by a variable name, then the match expression is assigned to that variable

The `case` expression does not assign to an existing variable, it creates a new variable which is only available within the body of the `case`.

It should read:

> If the `case` keyword is followed by a variable name, then a variable with that name is created and the matching value is assigned to that variable. The scope of the variable is the scope of the `case` body.

Answer (score 3):

```
val m = ???
val n = ???
val x = a match {
  case 2 => 22           //if a is 2 x=22
  case m: String => "aa" //if a is a String create new variable m, x="aa"
  case n: Int => 11      //if a is an Int create new variable n, x=11
}
//if m or n were created forget them, now out of scope
//only original (unchanged) m and n variables are visible
```